# Java class path in manifest not starting libraries

Tags: java

I have compiled a .jar file and I edited the archive of the MANIFEST.MF to add the Class-Path
I have a couple libraries that I need to be in the class-path in order to run the application, here is my classpath:

```
Class-Path: lib\commons-net-3.1.jar lib\org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar lib\prompt.jar lib\zip4j_1.3.2.jar
```

the folder config is like so:

Root directory ('dist'):

-lib folder

-myProgram.jar

So what am I doing wrong for the class-path not to recognize the libraries in the lib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
  lib/org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar
```

instead of

```
  lib\org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar
```

when adding libs in manifest

```
  Class-Path: lib/commons-net-3.1.jar lib/org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar lib/prompt.jar lib/zip4j_1.3.2.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use slashes instead of backslashes. Also make sure that the manifest ends with an empty line.